# Validation in gem carriarwave when change one column name filename on type:file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

When uploading a picture without validating everything is OK but once I add validate to the filename column, I can not upload the file.

I do not know if there is a bug on the database side or in the controller when creating, I think I will not pass the file name to the form.

The error is dropped when I have validation executed and no file ready to upload. When I turn on validate, the file can not be uploaded.

**Controller**

```
class ItemAttachmentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @item_attachments = ItemAttachment.all
  end

  def new
    @item_attachment = ItemAttachment.new
  end

  def create
    @item_attachment = ItemAttachment.new(item_attachment_params)
    @ID = @item_attachment.project_id
    #@item_attachment.filename = params[:file]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @item_attachment.save
        format.html { redirect_to project_path(@ID), notice: 'Item attachment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @item_attachment }
      else
        format.html { redirect_back fallback_location: root_path , alert: "Title or Attachment not to be filled" }
        format.json { render json: @item_attachment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end

  def item_attachment_params
    params.fetch(:item_attachment, {}).permit(:title, :description, :tag, :law, :project_id, :filename)
  end
  end
```

**app/uploaders/doc_uploader.rb (generate from gem carrierwave)**

```
class DocUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_whitelist
    %w(pdf doc html docx txt xlsx md jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

**app/models/item_attachment.rb**

```
class ItemAttachment < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :filename, DocUploader
  validates :filename, presence: true

  # filename can't be checked by validates...presence...true,
  # it always returns error:  can't be blank
end
```

**app/views/item_attachments/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@item_attachment) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
   <%= f.input :title %>
   <%= f.input :description %>
   <%= f.input :tag %>
   <%= f.input :law %>
   <%= f.association :project, selected: params[:project_id], :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => params[:project_id] } %>
   <%= f.input :filename, input_html: { :value => params[:filename] }, label: 'Upload Attachment', :required => true %>
 </div>

 <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

**Schema.rb**

```
  create_table "item_attachments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "description"
    t.string   "tag"
    t.string   "law"
    t.integer  "project_id"
    t.string   "filename",                 null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",               null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",               null: false
    t.index ["project_id"], name: "index_item_attachments_on_project_id", using: :btree
  end
```

**Console**

```
Started POST "/item_attachments" for 10.0.131.27 at 2017-06-27 13:41:50 +0200
Processing by ItemAttachmentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"zglXCxX4B8YLcaGlk+v8wr1gODFm/7B70KDDPZNjGA8Mc8E/txGpjKh20xCP93f1/vuH6BBGbzvWeAe9lu2FnQ==", "item_attachment"=>{"title"=>"asdasd", "description"=>"", "tag"=>"", "law"=>"", "project_id"=>"505", "filename_cache"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Item attachment"}
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
SQL (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO `item_attachments` (`title`, `description`, `tag`, `law`, `project_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('asdasd', '', '', '', 505, '2017-06-27 11:41:50', '2017-06-27 11:41:50')
(0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)

Mysql2::Error - Field 'filename' doesn't have a default value:
```

Answer (score 0):

searching in google for: "carrierwave validate file column"
returns this as first result:
https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/how-to:-validate-uploads-with-active-record

On your table migration you set the column filename so it can't be "null",

```
 t.string   "filename",                 null: false
```

and when you try to create it on your controller you don't pass a value to it, since you set it to not be null but didn't assign a default value to be used when one is not passed it gives you that error.

Since carrierwave "mounts" a column and does its magic on it, having "null: false" on the migration/schema isn't probably the correct way to handle file checking, because using a `default: "image_path"` doesn't work. You should probably take out that constraint and add on your model

validates_presence_of :uploader_name

And/or a default url
And https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#providing-a-default-url

Comment: I try this, i have in model item_attachment

Comment: I change null on true and add validation, as you wrote. But i try add file, first without file no error but next i try with file and error again, in console is many information about original_filename, content_tyep etc. how to get info to simple form with name or URL?

Comment: @TomášPutna, did you also rebuild the database? Otherwise the schema won't change and it will still prevent null's from being saved. You'll need to read carrierwave's Readme (you can find it on the last link on the answer) so you understand how to access its propertie, but for the url, in your case, it's .filename_url (you append _url to the column name). Last thing, you should look into using Postgresql instead of Mysql, it's a fairly better database for Rails.

Comment: i check my DB schema look good without null. Now i try delete validation and valid outpud when show in views filename like URL. So i allow add file without file with null params now working but is bad solution. when i try add jQuery on button witch is disable so when add file in the form button still not active another input like title when i write to input button became active. I think problem is in params when load file. But I do not know if the problem is here.

Comment: On the front end add both "required" to the file input field and e.preventDefault when the form is clicked so you can check for file validity (extension, size). Then do the same on the back-end, check for params[:file], add extension whitelisting to your uploader, you can also add filesize validation and lastly wrap the wtv.filename = Uploader.new ... wtv.save in a begin/end block so you can rescue any error. You can also use carrierwaves validates_presence_of, supposedly although I never used it so I'm not sure.